# Internet Explorer and Firefox crash, but Chrome doesn't?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer-8, crash

I have a system where either IE 8 or Firefox 3.5 will crash out without any error message, and do this spontaneously after about 1 or 2 minutes of being open.  Chrome, however, is stable and doesn't experience any of these problems.

What could be causing these browsers to exit, and without any determinable error message?  Is there something that links them together that is absent in Chrome?

Comment: Have you looked what windows application error log tells? Is there anything about these crashes written there?

Comment: Bad plugin? maybe the latest flash?

Comment: I reset IE to defaults, removed all plugins.  Same behavior.  Nothing in application log at all.

Comment: For which site or combination of sites does the crash occur? Do the browsers also crash when they're showing different sites, or just a blank page? Maybe it's not the browser but where you're surfing?

Comment: The crash occurs regardless of the site I am at.  I open the browser (either firfox or ie) and just let it sit at the default homepage.  After a few mins it just crashes without any preamble or loveletter to explain itself.

Comment: Can you get to web sites using IE and Firefox? - Nermind...I see you can get to web sites.

Comment: Yeah, I can visit any website I want.  It doesn't seem to effect the crash at all.  It seems to happen randomly, and not at trying to connect to any specific site.

Comment: Sounds strange...I would suspect Malware if the browsers are closing and no error messages are being recorded.  Have you run scans to help eliminate the possibility of Malware?

Comment: Try running Firefox in safemode and see if it still crashes.

Comment: Anything in about:crashes in Firefox?

Comment: Run memtest86+ to verify that your memory is not an issue. Different programs require different amounts of memory and it might be that firefox and IE usually loads on a certain address in your memory and crome does not.

Comment: Run Firefox in recovery mode, does it help?

Comment: I would suggest that a dll is corrupted, or malware may be the cause.